# MySQL multiple counting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | drink    | gender     |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | Beer     | m          |
|  2 | Milk     | f          |
|  3 | Milk     | f          |
|  4 | Tea      | m          |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Now I want to count which gender prefers which drink. The result should look like this:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| drink | fem   | male   |
+-------+-------+--------+
|  Beer | 0     | 1      |
|  Milk | 2     | 0      |
|  Tea  | 0     | 1      |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT drink,
       SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) fem,
       SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) male
FROM tableName
GROUP BY drink
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac3e8/1)

the query above can be further be converted into prepared statement. This is helpful, if for instance, you manage to add another value for the gender (*eg. `u` for unisex*) without modifying the original query. example,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when gender = ''',
      gender,
      ''' then 1 ELSE 0 end) AS ',
      gender
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT drink, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM tableName 
                   GROUP BY drink');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac3e8/2)